# OS X, Elixir, Ecto, Crypto, MySQL

Tags: mysql, elixir, ecto

Trying out Elixir & Ecto (not Phoenix) in a sample app to help me learn the language.

Running my program results in the following error:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 7-Apr-2016::16:23:28 ===
    application: logger
    exited: stopped
    type: temporary
** (Mix) Could not start application tpos: exited in: Tpos.start(:normal, [])
    ** (EXIT) exited in: GenServer.call(#PID<0.164.0>, {:get_all, Tpos.Data.Models.ProfitCenter}, 5000)
        ** (EXIT) exited in: GenServer.call(#PID<0.163.0>, {:checkout, :run}, 5000)
            ** (EXIT) exited in: GenServer.call(#PID<0.168.0>, {:connect, [hostname: "localhost", timeout: 5000, otp_app: :tpos, repo: Tpos.Repo, adapter: Ecto.Adapters.MySQL, database: "tpos", username: "tpos", password: "tpos", port: 3306]}, 5000)
                ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
                    ** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function :crypto.hash/2 (module :crypto is not available)
                        (crypto) :crypto.hash(:sha, "tpos")
                        (mariaex) lib/mariaex/protocol.ex:150: Mariaex.Protocol.mysql_native_password/2
                        (mariaex) lib/mariaex/protocol.ex:47: Mariaex.Protocol.dispatch/2
                        (mariaex) lib/mariaex/connection.ex:284: Mariaex.Connection.process/2
                        (mariaex) lib/mariaex/connection.ex:251: Mariaex.Connection.handle_info/2
                        (stdlib) gen_server.erl:615: :gen_server.try_dispatch/4
                        (stdlib) gen_server.erl:681: :gen_server.handle_msg/5
                        (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

If I do a `mix deps.clean --all` and a `mix.deps get` and run the program again, it works. But only once. If I exit and attempt to run it again, I receive the above error.

The line that causes the error is:

```
data = Repo.all(ProfitCenter)
```

As I said, the first time through this runs fine and returns the expected data. It's only on subsequent runs that the error pops up.

From mix.exs:

```
defmodule Tpos.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [app: :tpos,
     version: "0.0.1",
     elixir: "~> 1.2",
     build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
     start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
     deps: deps]
  end

  def application do
    [ applications: [:mariaex, :ecto],
      mod: { Tpos, [] } ]
  end

  defp deps do
    [
      {:credo, "~> 0.3", only: [:dev, :test]},
      {:mariaex, "~> 0.5.0"},
      {:ecto, "~> 1.1.5"},
      {:exactor, "~> 2.2.0"}
    ]
  end
end
```

I'm running OS X 10.11.1, and have tried several things to get it going based on advice like [this](https://solitum.net/openssl-os-x-el-capitan-and-brew/).

Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think you're missing the Erlang Crypto library.

Comment: @SashaFonseca, then why would it work at all?

Comment: it just crashes when the function call is made and the function is not found:

 undefined function :crypto.hash/2 (module :crypto is not available)

Usually Elixir will give a compile-time error if there's an undefined function but maybe it works differently for Erlang interoperability.

Comment: No. It works once. Subsequent runs result in a crash. So something is happening between run #1 and run #2.

Comment: what MySQL version are you using? I've seen some strange problems occur on 5.5

Comment: Have you installed Erlang with kerl?

Answer (score 1):

The error states that you don't have `:crypto` module. You can verify that by running:

```
iex(1)> Application.start(:crypto)
:ok
```

If you get anything else than `:ok`, it means that your Erlang installation is not fully functional. It happens very often when you install Erlang via `kerl`. Kerl doesn't consider lack of openssl an error. It just skips crytpo libraries without warning.

To install fully functional Erlang with kerl you need to run:

```
brew install openssl
brew install unixodbc
```

After that create `~/.kerlrc` file with following contents:

```
KERL_INSTALL_MANPAGES=yes
KERL_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS="--disable-hipe --enable-smp-support --enable-threads
                        --enable-kernel-poll --with-wx
                        --with-ssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl
                        --with-odbc=/usr/local/opt/unixodbc"
```

And try to reinstall Erlang. This config also adds `wx-widgets` which are handy if you want to run `:observer` application. Unixodbc also may come in handy, but less often.

If you are using different tool to install Erlang, you still need to point it to openssl path during compilation.

Alternatively, you can use packages provided by Erlang Solutions: https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html They should install all required dependencies including crypto.

Comment: I know the error says that. What perplexes me is that it works once. If crypto is needed for everything to work, and if crypto isn't there, then I can't understand why it would work at all.

Comment: You can check if in the first run `Mariaex.Protocol.mysql_native_password` is called at all. Maybe first run is somehow different? You can use `:dbg` to trace interesting modules and see how the runs differ from each other.